# how to get open contacts by calling method instead of button click

Tags: iphone

As per my requirement,

i need to get email id's from contacts.

And i need to write a code for this in a separate class in a method.To get call this integrate classes into my project simply call that method.

This is what i need.

for this my code in ownServices is like this.

```
-(NSString *)getSelectedNumberFromContatcs {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:NO];
    [peoplePickerController release];

    return aNSString;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    //  NSString *name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        CFStringRef phonenumberselected = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        //  CFStringRef emailLabelSelected = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier);
        //  CFStringRef emailLabelSelectedLocalized = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, identifier));

        aNSString = (NSString *)phonenumberselected;

        // Return to the main view controller.
        [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
        return NO;
    }   
    return YES ;
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];

}
```

i am calling this in myclassviewcontroller like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ownServices *obj = [[ownServices alloc]init];
    [obj getSelectedNumberFromContatcs];

    }
```

But contatcs viewcontraoller is not opened.

But i try same code in view controller in a button action like this

```
-(IBAction)openContacts {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:NO];
    [peoplePickerController release];

}
```

Then contacts viewconrtroller opened.

i did n't why view controller is not opened by calling it in a method.

is it possible to do like this.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the class you are using is inherited from NSObject not UIViewController so the [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:NO]; will not work. Also
 you have written this method in a wrong way

```
-(NSString *)getSelectedNumberFromContatcs {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePickerController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:peoplePickerController animated:NO];
    [peoplePickerController release];

    return aNSString;
}
```

Let me know what actually you want to do?

Comment: i need to open contacts by calling method and need to get selected email.Code must be written in another class for this.my sub classes are inherited from UIViewController only

Comment: Is there any specific reason to seperate the code. I can give you code for fetching contacts who has email. And further you can select which contact you want to use.

Comment: @MaheshBabu what is your e-mail address? I'll send code by mail

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `peoplePickerController.peoplePickerDelegate = self` is it possible to use the reference of your main View Controller?

Comment: No,there is no possibility of using main View Controller